# (Co-)Limits and fibrations of DG-Categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, dg-categories, limits-and-colimits, fibered-categories

First of all, let me see if I got the 1-categorical version right:

- Let $\mathcal  F:C\to Cat $ be a
  (pseudo-) functor. The 2-colimit
  $\mathrm{colim}_C\mathcal F$ is then
  given by the Grothendieck
  construction $\int_C \mathcal F$ and
  the 2-limit is given by the category
  of Cartesian sections of the
  fibration $\int_C \mathcal F\to  C$, right?

Can this be transported to the setting of dg$_k$-categories? So:

1. Is there a notion of fibration of dg
   categories? I would imagine them to
   be algebras for a dg-monad
   $(\mathrm{id}_C,-)$ arising from
   forming dg-comma categories with the
   identity-span on $C$.
2. What about a
   Grothendieck construction for
   functors $\mathcal F: C\to \mathrm{dgCat}$ from
   a category $C$ to dg-Categories?
3. Cartesian sections should then be
   defined as algebra-morphisms from
   the identity on $C$ to $\int_C
       \mathcal F$.

I think there are some problems with what i just said: What are dg-comma categories? What are the right functors $C\to\mathrm{dgCat}$? (I guess one should build a dg-category $C'$ out of $C$ by taking the free $k$-category and then consider it as a dg-category, concentrated in degree 0, and then consider $\mathrm{dgCat}(C',\mathrm{dgCat})$) Same goes for the definition of an algebra morphism: What are the coherences to consider?

So I guess the core question is:

- What is the right notion of limit for dg categories? (And why?)

Comment: The Grothendieck construction is the "oplax-colimit", to get the 2-colimit, you must invert the Cartesian morphisms.

Comment: Hm... wether it is the lax- or oplax-colimit depends on how you define the grothendieck construction: you chose the vertical part of a morphism to be either $f_*x\to x'$ or $x' \to f_*x$; both work equally and we have

$\int'_C F = \int_C op \circ F$ 